# How apply texture on SVG Group with THREE.JS?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a raised relief map using an SVG shape and apply a texture to it. I've load the SVG file and position it in my scene, but I'm struggling to apply the texture to the group. The texture is loaded correctly but I don't see it. Have any of you encountered the same issue?

```
        this.loaderTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        this.texture = this.loaderTexture.load('./assets/img/textures/texture.jpg');
        let height = this.loaderTexture.load('./assets/img/textures/height.jpg');

        // Load SVG
        const loader = new SVGLoader();
        loader.load('./assets/img/textures/map.svg', (data) => {
            const paths = data.paths;
            const group = new THREE.Group();

            const geometries = [];

            for (const path of paths) {
                const shapes = SVGLoader.createShapes(path);

                for (const shape of shapes) {
                    const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
                    geometries.push(geometry); 
                }
            }

            const mergedGeometry =  new BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries(geometries);
            const materialGroup = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                color: 'gray',
                map: this.texture, // Appliquer la texture au matériau
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                displacementMap: height,
                displacementScale: 100
            });

            const groupMesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, materialGroup);
            const transformationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(1, -1, 1);
            groupMesh.applyMatrix4(transformationMatrix);
            groupMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
            groupMesh.position.set(-350, -200, -800);

            this.scene.add(groupMesh);
        });
```